# Rate module: rate icon disappears and no vote is recorded

Tags: rating

I am having a problem with the rate module. I have implemented it on node 'project' and it appears. When I click on 'thumbs up', the icon disappears. It looks like the AJAX is not working.

Comment: What version of the Rate module do you use? Have you tried the stable or the dev? Also try a new clean drupal install with the default theme (dont use omega) and see if the problem still exists. Also maybe try with another browser. You might have some adblocker or other browser extension that breaks the ajax process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve this issue by enabling Clean URLs (configuration -> clean URLs).  Note, if you are prompted with a Clean URLs test that inevitably fails, you will likely need to uncomment the "RewriteBase" line in your .htaccess file.