# Votes are not saved on refresh for Rate module

Tags: rating

I am using rate module and created a rate widget for a content type with voting option as thumbs up/down.Set Interaction as 'Users vote if available, empty otherwise' and 'Users vote' for Which rating should be displayed when the user just voted.

I can vote the content but on node refresh its gone! and by default vote is shown as 50%

Votes are not getting saved. Is there any other setting I need to do? and Do I need to have BotScout.com API key to get the votes save?

I checked for earlier [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41455/rate-module-rate-icon-disappears-and-no-vote-is-recorded) but it was not helpful.

Comment: Is it about the cache?

Comment: I really do not have idea! but yes when I vote as thumbs up or down, at log warning 'Cache rebuild lock hit: event_init' for type rules .

Comment: do you have the VotingAPI installed?

Comment: yes..! It is enabled by default